# Asp.net add item to dropdownlist from javascript and submit form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Good afternoon,

I have the following problem. I had a dropdownlist of position which is default loaded from database. A link **Add** is used to open a popup for adding new position.

[image]

I can manage to add new item to the dropdownlist via jquery but when I submit the button **Save** for saving record, I got the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.    Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or
>   callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event
>   validation is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. 
>   For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.]
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
>   String argument) +8646569
>   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String
>   eventArgument) +69
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +53
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData,
>   Boolean fBeforeLoad) +343
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1743
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459

I have no idea what exactly the problem is, and how to solve it.

Here is my raw html code:

```
<div class="addNew" title="Add New Position Title">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Position Title</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPositionTitle" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>            
    </table>
</div>   




<table class="ui-accordion">
    <tr>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="PoTitle" DataValueField="ID" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">...</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName="WH.Service.PositionService"></asp:ObjectDataSource>         

            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Add</asp:HyperLink> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Qualification</td>
        <td>

                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstQualification" runat="server" DataSourceID="oDsQualification" DataTextField="QName" DataValueField="ID" RepeatColumns="4" Width="800px" CssClass="TOG_CHECK">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="oDsQualification" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName="WH.Service.QualificationService"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".addNew").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            close: function (event, ui) {
                //location.reload(false);
            },
            buttons:
            {
                "Add": function () {
                    var poTitle = $("#<%= this.txtPositionTitle.ClientID  %>").val();


                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Helper/WhHelper.asmx/AddNewPosition',
                        data: '{"PoTitle":"' + poTitle + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            if (msg.d) {
                                //Alert successfull saving record
                                alert("Successfully added new item");                                  

                                //Adding item to selection list
                                var p = msg.d;                                   
                                $('#<%= this.DropDownList1.ClientID %>').append('<option value="' + p.ID + '" selected="true">' + p.PoTitle + '</option>');

                                //Close Dialog Box
                                $(".addNew").dialog("close");
                            }

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error! Try again...");
                        }
                    });

                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#<%= this.HyperLink2.ClientID %>").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".addNew").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any code in `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your system is detecting that the data sent to the server has been altered on client.

Your system is checking that the control data that is sent to server originates on the same server, and as you're adding a new option to the dropdownlist, it flags it as potentially malicious data. That's the reason for the error.

I think you can avoid this default behaviour adding

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

to your page, so the client event validation isn't done and the change to your dropdownlist isn't registered as dangerous.

Comment: Is it a safe way, to do so?

Comment: This will disable the additional checks that the framework makes against your forms to check for client alteration.

Probably a safer way to solve the problem would be to modify the dropdownlist on server code, to avoid the checking to detect the alteration on client code and flag it as a false positive, however, it's due to you to choose between your page's intended behaviour and it's security level. 

Unchecking client even validation can open your page to some potential attacks, so choose wisely